# Static ip setup breaks internet connection

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, netgear, static-ip

#### Specs

OS: Ubuntu 12.0.4 Server 
Router: Netgear Genie WNDR3700v2

#### Goal

To give my Ubuntu server a static ip address so I could eventually forward a router port to it and make it accessible via the internet.

#### Background

I disabled ipv6 by adding the below lines to the bottom of my /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

#### Problem

Once I setup a static ip using the below /etc/network/interfaces file, I can't connect to the internet.

#### /etc/network/interfaces

```
  1 # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
  2 # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
  3 
  4 # The loopback network interface
  5 auto lo
  6 iface lo inet loopback
  7 
  8 # The primary network interface
  9 auto eth0
 10 iface eth0 inet static
 11 address 192.168.0.111
 12 netmask 255.255.255.0
 13 gateway 192.168.0.0
 14 network 192.168.0.1
 15 broadcast 192.168.0.255
 16 dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
 17 
 18 # This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
 19 # iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Any ideas or suggestions for troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the gateway (192.168.0.0) and network (192.168.0.1) addresses switched around?

Comment: Nope, tried switching them, and setting both to .1 and 'sudo ifup -a' still returns 'failed to bring up eth0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the below field in my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
address 192.168.0.222
```

Turns out that the previous value of `192.168.0.111` was in the range reserved for DHCP by my router.